# cmath and math.h giving different answers

Tags: c++, floating-point

When I use the atan function from cmath and math on a floating point number, I seem to get different answers:

```
#include <cmath>  
#include <math.h>                                                                              

#include <iostream>                                                             
#include <iomanip>                                                              

int main() {                                                                
    std::cout << std::setprecision(20) << atan(-0.57468467f) << std::endl;   
    std::cout << std::setprecision(20) << std::atan(-0.57468467f) << std::endl;  

    // I get:
    // -0.52159727580733605823
    // -0.52159726619720458984
}
```

Why does this happen? Does two libraries implement atan differently?

Comment: I'm willing to bet one has to convert it to a double.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`math.h`'s `atan` takes a double and returns a double, yet `cmath`'s is overloaded so that a float argument (as used here) will be used as a float and yield a float result.  Thus, the difference in output comes from using two different floating-point types.  To make them use the same type, either remove the `f` at the ends of the numbers or change the first `atan` to `atanf`.

Comment: So in other words, on the first line, I'm printing a double and on the second line, I'm printing a float?

Comment: @Peter: No. The difference is that the `atan` called in the first line returns a `double`, so it is able to return a more accurate value. The routine called in the second line can only return a `float`. The type used for printing is largely irrelevant in this case.